# Why and when to use AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater?

Tags: java, concurrency, atomic

Why and when should one use these classes?

- `AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater`
- `AtomicMarkableReference`
- `AtomicReference`

Kindly explain using a real life scenario!

Answer (score 9):

`AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater` can be used if said field needs to be used as just regular volatile field (without declaring them as `AtomicXXX` class) but needs atomic operations occasionally. Also, if you are creating a lot of objects and you don't want to create a lot of `AtomicXXX` objects, you can create a static `AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater` object and let it be shared between all the objects. This [article](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_concurrency_7_atomic_updaters.shtml) explains more in detail.

Comment: I don't think your description really explains how and when to use `AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater`, but the link you reference does.